# How to execute this python media player?

Tags: python, wxpython

I just copy pasted this media player in python .When I am running this using the command `python mediaplayer.py` (mediaplayer.py is my filwename) there is no output .Can anyone tell why?

```
import os
import time
import wx
import MplayerCtrl as mpc
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
bitmapDir = os.path.join(dirName,'bitmaps')
```

class Frame(wx.Frame):

```
def __init__(self,parent,id,title,mplayer):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
     self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

    sp = wx.StandardPaths.Get()
    self.currentFolder = sp.GetDocumentsDir()
    self.currentVolume = 50

    self.create_menu()

    # create sizers
    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    controlSizer = self.build_controls()
    sliderSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    self.mplayer = mpc.MplayerCtrl(self.panel, -1, mplayer)
    self.playbackSlider = wx.Slider(self.panel, size=wx.DefaultSize)
    sliderSizer.Add(self.playbackSlider, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

    # create volume control
    self.volumeCtrl = wx.Slider(self.panel)
    self.volumeCtrl.SetRange(0, 100)
    self.volumeCtrl.SetValue(self.currentVolume)
    self.volumeCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.on_set_volume)
    controlSizer.Add(self.volumeCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

    # create track counter
    self.trackCounter = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="00:00")
    sliderSizer.Add(self.trackCounter, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

    # set up playback timer
    self.playbackTimer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_update_playback)

    mainSizer.Add(self.mplayer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    mainSizer.Add(sliderSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    mainSizer.Add(controlSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    self.panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    self.Bind(mpc.EVT_MEDIA_STARTED, self.on_media_started)
    self.Bind(mpc.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.on_media_finished)
    self.Bind(mpc.EVT_PROCESS_STARTED, self.on_process_started)
    self.Bind(mpc.EVT_PROCESS_STOPPED, self.on_process_stopped)

    self.Show()
    self.panel.Layout()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def build_btn(self, btnDict, sizer):
    """"""
    bmp = btnDict['bitmap']
    handler = btnDict['handler']

    img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, bmp))
    btn = buttons.GenBitmapButton(self.panel, bitmap=img,
                                  name=btnDict['name'])
    btn.SetInitialSize()
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler)
    sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.LEFT, 3)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def build_controls(self):
    """
    Builds the audio bar controls
    """
    controlSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    btnData = [{'bitmap':'player_pause.png',
                'handler':self.on_pause, 'name':'pause'},
               {'bitmap':'player_stop.png',
                'handler':self.on_stop, 'name':'stop'}]
    for btn in btnData:
        self.build_btn(btn, controlSizer)

    return controlSizer

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_menu(self):
    """
    Creates a menu
    """
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    add_file_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&Add File", "Add Media File")
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')

    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_add_file, add_file_menu_item)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_add_file(self, event):
    """
    Add a Movie and start playing it
    """
    wildcard = "Media Files (*.*)|*.*"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultDir=self.currentFolder,
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        self.currentFolder = os.path.dirname(path[0])
        trackPath = '"%s"' % path.replace("\\", "/")
        self.mplayer.Loadfile(trackPath)

        t_len = self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()
        self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
        self.playbackTimer.Start(100)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_media_started(self, event):
    print 'Media started!'

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_media_finished(self, event):
    print 'Media finished!'
    self.playbackTimer.Stop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_pause(self, event):
    """"""
    if self.playbackTimer.IsRunning():
        print "pausing..."
        self.mplayer.Pause()
        self.playbackTimer.Stop()
    else:
        print "unpausing..."
        self.mplayer.Pause()
        self.playbackTimer.Start()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_process_started(self, event):
    print 'Process started!'

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_process_stopped(self, event):
    print 'Process stopped!'

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_set_volume(self, event):
    """
    Sets the volume of the music player
    """
    self.currentVolume = self.volumeCtrl.GetValue()
    self.mplayer.SetProperty("volume", self.currentVolume)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_stop(self, event):
    """"""
    print "stopping..."
    self.mplayer.Stop()
    self.playbackTimer.Stop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def on_update_playback(self, event):
    """
    Updates playback slider and track counter
    """
    try:
        offset = self.mplayer.GetTimePos()
    except:
        return
    print offset
    mod_off = str(offset)[-1]
    if mod_off == '0':
        print "mod_off"
        offset = int(offset)
        self.playbackSlider.SetValue(offset)
        secsPlayed = time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(offset))
        self.trackCounter.SetLabel(secsPlayed)
```

Comment: How about actually creating an object of your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not meant to be used as you posted it.

The class needs to be instantiated, and possibly run in a main loop of some sort.

In addition, as you can see on the line `import MplayerCtrl as mpc`, it *isn't* a stand-alone.

Please post at minimum a link to where you downloaded it.

Also, be aware it appears to be a **wrapper** around a real media player that implements a wxPython interface, not a full media player, so you'll still need the actual application (I assume mplayer based on the naming) for it to do anything.